# Iterations inside of styled components

Tags: javascript, styled-components

I've got theme object which looks like:

```
{
  h1: {
    color: red
  },
  h2: {
    color: blue
  }
}
```

And I would  like to iterate through that object and dynamically create styled-component style definitions like:

```
createGlobalStyle`
   ${props => Object.keys(props.theme).map(header => {
     return css`
     ${header}: {
       color: ${props.theme[header].color;
     }
     ` 
   }
`
```

The problem is that it is not working :(

Have you maybe idea how to do so basic stuff like iterating through the object and dynamically create additional tagged styles?

Comment: Lurkers: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly your `createGlobalStyle` code example is a bit of a mess missing closing `)` and `}` all over.

Secondly `Object.keys(props.theme).map(...)` will return an `Array`.

You should be aiming to at least return a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from that example block.

Thirdly, CSS classes targeting tagnames aren't defined with colons:

```
${header}: {
    color: ${props.theme[header].color;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```
${({ theme }) => {
    let templateLiteral = ``;
    Object.keys(theme).forEach(n => {
        templateLiteral += `
            .${n} {
                color: red;
            }
        `;
    });
    return templateLiteral;
}}
```